# CameraRoll & ListView crashes assetsd

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get the CameraRoll & ListView correctly running on REACT-NATIVE. I've used the CameraRoll-Example as the foundation. In the simulator it works with about 5 images. On my iPhone 5S(iOS 8.3) I'm getting the following error:

```
RCTJSLog> "Warning: ScrollView doesn't take rejection well - scrolls     anyway"
Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd    died
```

Then I was trying the UIExplorer example on my iPhone. Same results. Maybe one of u guys know how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

By default, React Native returns full-resolution images to the image component. Displaying so much data at once can result in a crashed application. You can return smaller versions by adjusting line 48 of libraries > RCTImage > RCTImageLoader.m

For example, to return thumbnails:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail] scale:1.0f orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation];
```